# js - backreference not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

I have a string "styles-123.min.js", that I want to replace with "styles-456.min.js". So I do this:

```
str = "styles-123.min.js";
str = str.replace(/(styles|apps)/, "$0" + "-456");

alert(str)
```

The $0 isn't parsed and the result is "$0-456-min.js". Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, use `$&` instead of `$0` to refer to the whole match value.

See the [`String#replace()` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> `$&`  Inserts the matched substring.

If you do not use `$1`, there is no point in the capturing group in the pattern, you can use

```js
str = "styles-123.min.js";
str = str.replace(/styles|apps/, "$&-456");
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check for `-123` using following regex.

**Regex:** `-\d+`

**Javascript Code**

```js
str = "styles-123.min.js";
str = str.replace(/-\d+/, "-456");
alert(str);
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB6zZ2/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You could do (`$1` means the first matched group):

```js
str = "styles-123.min.js";
str = str.replace(/(styles|apps)[0-9-]+/, "$1-456");

alert(str);
```